# Cannot fins EduRoster permissions on Azure portal

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azureportal, microsoft-graph-edu

I'm trying to use Education APIs which is now in `beta`. When I call:

```
/education/me/classes
```

I'm getting the error `AccessDenied` with the message `Required scp claim values are not provided.`

The [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/educationuser_list_classes) says I need to set `EduRoster` permissions but I can't find anything similar in the Azure Portal (Azure Active Directory->Required permissions->Microsoft Graph)

Could someone please help me to find them? Or maybe the error means something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone please help me to find them? Or maybe the error means something else?

We need to check the [**Read the organization's roster**] from the Microsoft Graph. For more detail information, please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

We also could check the bearer token permission via https://jwt.io/

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately setting this permission did not resolve my issue. I'm still getting the error `Required scp claim values are not provided`. Will rise new ticket.

Comment: please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48639615/microsoft-graph-api-error-required-scp-claim-values-are-not-provided