# Microsoft Graph API error "Required scp claim values are not provided"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

Given I'm logged in with MSSSO account;

And the `Read the organization's roster` permission is set;

When I call `/education/me/classes` endpoint;

Then I get the 403 response with the code `AccessDenied` and the message `Required scp claim values are not provided`.

What does the error mean? How do I fix it?

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/22d54f2b-1771-400c-8839-1b661d1d5270/",
  "iat": 1517909669,
  "nbf": 1517909669,
  "exp": 1517913569,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "Y2NgYLj3Um+jDePa8FgXu/w7Jkl3lHo0ZbNPdx498+y09QQTG3UA",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "My company ",
  "appid": "5a993391-9e90-45e8-9823-e6ba00f810f3",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "family_name": "user",
  "given_name": "user",
  "ipaddr": "91.244.25.19",
  "name": "user",
  "oid": "bb0571c2-e60d-4425-8c37-5cd7fabe5083",
  "platf": "5",
  "puid": "10033FFF9E13F0A0",
  "scp": "Contacts.Read Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All email Files.Read Files.Read.All Group.Read.All Mail.Read.Shared Mail.Send offline_access openid People.Read profile User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All",
  "sub": "rq0gSA1ps5tiFGaN1n84WZEeqqBU5pKhv-cMJQRwpSw",
  "tid": "22d54f2b-1771-400c-8839-1b661d1d5270",
  "unique_name": "user@company.com",
  "upn": "user@company.com",
  "uti": "ARRvKJOO6UutMlcwAPgYAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: According to your mentioned information : there is no `EduRoster.Read.All`  premission in scp. As I mentioned in another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536356/cannot-fins-eduroster-permissions-on-azure-portal), you need to check the [Read the organization's roster] and click **Grant Premissions** from azure portal.

Comment: I did set `Read the organization's roster` permission and I did `Grant Premissions`

Comment: You could check **scp** field in your mentioned code .

Comment: Without seeing how you're generating this token, it will be a challenge to sort out what is happening.

Comment: 1. I click login button on my webpage.

2. I'm redirected to the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=.....` page

3. I sign in

4. I'm redirected back to my page with `code`, `state ` and `session_state `.

5. I exchange `code` by making request to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token` endpoint and get `token_type`, `scope`, `expires_in`, `ext_expires_in`, `expires_on`, `not_before`, `resource`, `access_token`, `refresh_token` and `id_token `.

Comment: Have you re-consented the application with admin consent endpoint since you modified the application's scopes to include the rostering permission?   Also you should be using EduRoster.ReadBasic

Comment: That was the part I missed. Thank you @GarethJ